# Assertion error in Mocha while testing the smart contract

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, solidity

I am testing my Ethereum smart contract and getting an assertion error as one of the test case is failing.

```
Contract: Market
✓ contract is deployed

  1 passing (142ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: Market
   offer added:
   AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError
```

Here is code:

```
contract('Market', ()=>{
it('contract is deployed',async ()=>{
    const market = await Market.deployed();
    assert(market.address!='');
    })
it('offer added', async () =>{
    const market = await Market.deployed();    
    let oldVal = await market.numOffers();
    market.supplyRequest(1,10,1);
    let newVal = await market.numOffers();
    console.log("new value is "+newVal); //this prints 1 on console
    console.log("old value is "+oldVal); // this print 0 on console
    assert(oldVal+1==newVal);
 });
});
```

I am not sure why the test case is failing even when the values are equal.

Comment: Is it possible that your numOffers method is returning a string? Because oldVal +1 would return '11' in case it is a string.  
Can you provide the numOffers method or at least the console.log value of the oldVal + 1

Comment: That's precisely what's happening. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numOffers is probably returning a string and not a number, that is why the +1 in the assert changes the value from '1' to '11' and the assertion fails.